# How to check if a socket.id is joined in a specific room?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm working on a Socket.io application and I need to check the `socket.id` of a client in a specific room. How can I achieve this?

```
import { socketIds } from "../models/connection/connectionEvents.js";

//socketIds is a global object where I store all the clients connected 

export  async function informOperator(io,senderSocketId,conversationData,eventName,eventData) {
  try {
    //search for the operators socket ids in the global array socketIds
    Object.entries(socketIds).forEach(([socketId, user]) => {
      if ( senderSocketId !== socketId &&
        user.userId.find(userId => conversationData.operators.includes(userId))
      ) {
             //I want here to check if the socketId is in the room conversationData._id 
        io.to(socketId).emit(eventName,...eventData)
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error; 
  }
}
```

i'm using :
"socket.io": "^4.5.4",
"socket.io-client": "^4.5.4",

I tried :
1)io.sockets.manager.rooms['/' + room].indexOf(socket.id) >= 0
2 const socketInRoom = room.has(socketId);

Answer (score 0):

I solve with this : io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomName)?.has(socketId)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).